# npm throwing error about missing module '../'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

I'm running a react-native app right now, and even though the simulation runs perfectly on iOS when I run `react-native run-ios`, if I run `npm start` to run the app on a physical device, npm throws the following error:

```
> Project@0.0.1 start /Users/zavtra/Development/App-RN
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zavtra/Development/App-RN/node_modules/.bin/which:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

How can a module be named `../`? I didn't change anything in the modules and I can't figure out why this error is suddenly occurring. Is there something I have to install/uninstall for the server to work again?

I ran `npm install` as well and updated my npm/node. No dice.

Comment: what's your physical device?

Comment: The device is an iPhone 6s

Comment: It was loading it from a URL. At this point I ran `react-native init newproject` and basically rebuilt the project clean.

Comment: Apologies, I deleted my comment as I realised that this was an error on your console and not on your device.